# How to get src of upload file using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use a function to create thumbnails for which I need the `src` of the uploaded image. How can I get that?

Following is the function that I'm interested in:

```
function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width) {
    /* read the source image */
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);

    /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
    $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
    imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);
}
```

Your help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$src will be your original uploaded image

$dest will be the resized image

These will both be file system paths. Assuming that both of these paths exist under the document root you can  translate those to a url by just trim off the $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]

```
  $url = str_replace($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], realpath($dest));
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual image source is in $source_image (it will be a resource).

You can always `file_get_contents($src)` if you wanted the raw data...